# Some help understanding probability notation

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

Can someone write the below expression out to me in plain English? I don't have a stats background and so am not sure how to interpret the notation. Any links to this notation would also be welcome, trying to search for the special characters isn't going well.

$Pr\{Q = y|r\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not give enough detail to answer for sure.

One possibility is that random variable $Q$ is distributed according to a member of a family of discrete distributions with parameter $r.$ [If the distribution of $Q$ were continuous, then the probability would be $0,$ without further computation.]

For example, let $Q \sim \mathsf{Pois}(r = 2),$ So $E(Q)=2.$ Then $$P(Q=3|r = 2) = e^{-2}2^3/3! = 0.1804,$$ to four places. Computation in R:

```
dpois(3, 2)
[1] 0.180447
exp(-2)*2^3/factorial(3)
[1] 0.180447
```

But I suppose another possibility would be that $Q$ and $R$ are jointly distributed random variables and your expression is a conditional probability of $Q$ given a particular value of $r$ of $R.$

Comment: as good as it gets for an answer, I believe that it is option #2! :)